How Git sort entries in trees?
I use command like git cat-file -p {tree_hash} and see, that files sorted in special way. It is not Lexicographical order, because if we have entries in lexicographical order:
entrie,
entrie-dopes,
entrie-hope,
entrie-сase

Git will sort them in order like
entrie-сase,
entrie-dopes,
entrie-hope,
entrie

So my question is: What kind of sorting method is this?.

Why? Are you asking generally how to sort nothing after something, or do you need to predict git's output? If the former, remove git from your question. If the latter, there is probably a better solution.

How is this related to GitHub and the JGit Java library? (If it isn't related, please remove the tags)

Are the commas just for enumeration or are they part of the names?

@j6t commas for enumeartion, not a part of names

@Gaberocksall i find info about lexicographical sorting of entries in trees, but in fact my case working in a wrong way, thats why i ask about kinf of sorting that git uses bcs it is not lexicographical

Just a point: d h c is not lexicographical order ...

@LeGEC in such case there is lexicographical order, try it

ok :D perhaps you could specify that the c in your question is actually a russian с (unicode point U+0441, UTF-8 \xC1\x81) ? If your question specifically relates to how git handles russian alphabet wand latin alphabet, I would also suggest to mention that in your question more explicitly.

Git sorts entries in trees in lexicographic order using unsigned byte values. Encoding of names like UTF-8 is irrelevant.
There is one exception: Entries that are sub-trees are ordered as if the name has a slash / appended. For this reason, you get this order:
entrie
entrie-case
entrie=case

when entrie is a file, but
entrie-case
entrie
entrie=case

when entrie is a directory.
A remark in the Git source code mentions this.

I had searched in vain why folders behaved here in an odd way, but thanks to your answer it dawned on me. Brilliant.

This answers makes me wonder if we should document stuff like this pointing to git code.... That would be awesome!!! I have pointed to code here or there...  Might be a great way to get acquainted with the code. Thanks for the answer... It's a good one.

Am i understand you correct: if git see name like "entrie-case" it interprets this like "entrie/case" and then compare it unsigned byte values?

@AlexanderStrigunov No. "entrie" is "entrie" if it is the name of a file, but "entrie" is interpreted as "entrie/" if it is the name of a directory.

@eftshift0 I added one mention of this quirk in the source code.
